# Multiplicative Limits in Banach Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, banach-algebras

Let $(a_n), (b_n)$ be sequences in a Banach algebra and $(c_n) := (a_n.b_n)$

**If $\lim (c_n) = c$ and $\lim (a_n) = a $ does it follow that $(b_n)$ has a limit $b$ satisfying $c = a.b$ ?**

I can see this result if the sequence $(a_n)$ is invertible, but this isn't guaranteed in a general Banach algebra. Some sort of proof by contradiction seems possible ?

---

I know I shouldn't really change the question, but rather than posting a new one let me ask in the light of feedback...

**Is this true if $a \ne 0$ ?**

---

**Note**: Let $B^\times$ be the set of invertible elements of $B$. If $a$ is invertible then because $B^\times$ is an open set, the tail of the sequence is invertible.  Furthermore the inverse function $\phi: B^\times \to B^\times: \phi(x) = x^{-1}$ is continuous and therefore sequentially continuous.
(Ref: Megginson An Introduction to Banach Space Theory p.310)

Then $\lim a_i = a \implies \lim a_i^{-1} = a^{-1}$ (at least as this applies to the invertible tail of the sequence).

As a standard result on limits $\lim x_i = x$ and  $\lim y_i = y$ then $\lim x_i.y_i = x.y$

So, $\lim [(a_i^{-1}).(a_i.b_i)] = \lim b_i = a^{-1}.c$

I.e. **the result holds if $a$ is invertible**

Comment: This isn't even true for real numbers. Take $a_n = n^{-2}$ and $b_n = n$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks, but what if $a \ne 0$

Comment: I don't think that is strong enough either. You could define your Banach algebra so that the subalgebra that the $a_n$ live in has a product of $0$ with the subalgebra that the $b_n$ live in. Take for example different diagonal blocks in a block matrix. Note that the $a_n$ wouldn't be invertible.

Comment: Taking cues from everything else herein, we probably need $a$ to be invertible for $b$ to exist. But since the invertible elements in a Banach algebra form an open set, this means that eventually $a_n$ is invertible. At which point I think you can do regular triangle inequality stuff to argue that the $b_n$ are Cauchy

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks. I added a note accordingly - hope it's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't even true in $\mathbb{C}$. Take $a_n=c_n=0$ and $b_n=(-1)^n$.

**Edit:** If you want $a\ne 0$ then consider $A=M_2(\mathbb{C})$ and the following sequences: $a_n=\begin{pmatrix}1&0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{n} \end{pmatrix}, b_n=\begin{pmatrix}1&0 \\ 0 & (-1)^n \end{pmatrix}, c_n=\begin{pmatrix}1&0 \\ 0 & \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \end{pmatrix}$. Note that here the elements of $a_n$ are even invertible.

Comment: Hah wow. Check the verbiage in my comment above. Another good counter example!

Comment: Thanks, but what if $a \ne 0$

Comment: Yours goes a step further to show boundedness isn't enough but doesn't rule out a convergent subsequence. Ultimately I suspect you can't get away without assuming a condition like invertibility (or a weakening thereof).

Comment: @Tom Collinge Ok, I edited my answer.